# Why my app crashes when I try to sign in with Google in ios-prod flavor?

Tags: flutter, firebase

I am trying to set up different firebase projects for development and production with flavors and xCode schemes. **It works well in Android**. But, in **IOS**, when I try to sign in with [google_sign_in](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in) with the **prod flavor** it crashes the app, without any output. **In the dev flavor it also works well**.

To set up this I followed [this post](https://kmtsandeepanie.medium.com/set-up-multiple-firebase-environments-in-flutter-9f88bc284454)

I think the problem may be here:

To change the differents *REVERSED_CLIENT_ID* depending on the flavor I did this (this also is included on the post I mentioned before):

I added this to `ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig` and `ios/Flutter/Release.xcconfig`

```
GOOGLE_SERVICE_REVERSED_CLIENT_ID = {Your REVERSED_CLIENT_ID found in GoogleService-Info.plist file}
```

On my `ios/Runner/info.plist` I changed this:

```
    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
    <array>
      <string>myOldReversedClientId</string>
    </array>
```

To this:

```
    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
    <array>
      <string>$(GOOGLE_SERVICE_REVERSED_CLIENT_ID)</string>
    </array>
```

And finally in xCode in `Build Settings -> User-Defined` I defined my variable *GOOGLE_SERVICE_REVERSED_CLIENT_ID* according to each enviroment:

```
Debug-dev = com.googleusercontent.apps.{dev client-id}
Debug-prod = com.googleusercontent.apps.{prod client-id}
Profile-dev = com.googleusercontent.apps.{dev client-id}
Profile-prod = com.googleusercontent.apps.{prod client-id}
Release-dev = com.googleusercontent.apps.{dev client-id}
Release-prod = com.googleusercontent.apps.{prod client-id}
```

(obviously, using the *REVERSED_CLIENT_ID* of each GoogleService-Info.plist)

Also, when I implement the `GoogleSignIn` class I do it this way:

```
 GoogleSignIn(clientId: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform.iosClientId).signIn()
```

I don't have a `GoogleService-Info.plist` file on my `ios/runner` folder

As it works for the dev-flavor but it doesn't for the prod-flavor, I think that it could be a problem when I implement the `GoogleSignIn` class and I define the `clientId`. Maybe I'm passing an Id which works for the dev-flavor but not for the prod-flavor, but I'm not sure and I don't know which other alternative I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

I have to sign in this way:

```
 GoogleSignIn().signIn()
```